# How to collect data without a database

Tags: php, html

I am making a coming soon page for my website and it including text-box for name and email I am working on asp but now I want php or html5 coding since I complete my project.

I want to insert the data in a csv file and also send a auto generated mail on the user email address with php  is it possible and how can anyone help me out of this.
 Have two textbox name and email.
Can you give me the code as I am new in php?

The code I found on google:

```
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $errorMessage = ""; 
    if(empty($_POST['name']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>without name how can we send you invitation</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>i think email id is required</li>";
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","a");
        fwrite($fs,$name . ", " . $email . "\n");
        fclose($fs);

        header("Location: werememberyou.html");
        exit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your current code

1. Email to specific entry.

   You can use Direct Mail function of php. Or you can use [PHP Mailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) (for localhost testing its best)
2. Adding Entry to CSV file.

   Here you can have a problem in future to add new entry to your current file. so i have added some code which you can use.

   ```
   if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
   {
       $errorMessage = ""; 
       if(empty($_POST['name']))
       {
           $errorMessage .= "<li>without name how can we send you invitation</li>";
       }
       if(empty($_POST['email']))
       {
           $errorMessage .= "<li>i think email id is required</li>";
       }

       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];

       function array_insert($array, $pos, $val)
       {
           $array2 = array_splice($array, $pos);
           $array[] = $val;
           $array = array_merge($array, $array2);
           return $array;
       } 

       if(empty($errorMessage)) 
       {

           $DataToInsert = $name.','.$email;
           $PositionToInsert = 1;

           //Full path & Name of the CSV File
           $FileName = 'mydata.csv';

           //Read the file and get is as a array of lines.
           $arrLines = file($FileName);

           //Insert data into this array.
           $Result = array_insert($arrLines, $PositionToInsert, $DataToInsert);

           //Convert result array to string.
           $ResultStr = implode("\n", $Result);

           //Write to the file.
           file_put_contents($FileName, $ResultStr);

           $to      = $email;
           $subject = 'Thank You';
           $message = 'We will soon contact you';
           $headers = 'From: youremail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
                      'Reply-To: youremail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
                      'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

           mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


           header("Location: werememberyou.html");
           exit;
       }
   ```

Comment: @css3schools.comSahilPopli Yes 2 changes. I have posted it.

Comment: @css3schools.comSahilPopli Fine, I have tested here and working fine. Let me know if any prob.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.fputcsv.php), this function will prepare correct data for structure of csv files. Just create an array with collected data and pass it as parameter. I see you have opened your file with "a" parameter already, so you're good.

Sending mail is easy if your sever is configured properly, use [mail](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.mail.php) function.

You'll find everything you need (with examples) on [php.net](http://www.php.net/) and I strongly recommend it as first source of information.